# JSP placed in WebContent does not find file

Tags: java, jsp

Jsp page is placed in WebContent. File is placed in WebContent\img.
I try to use style like this:

```
background-image: url(img/background.jpg);
```

It doesn't work. But if JSP page is placed in WebContent\WEB-INF it will work.

I also tried:

```
background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
background-image: url(/img/background.jpg);
```

UPD:

When the other page placed in WEB-INF redirect to the JSP in WebContent than the latter sees file.

Background.jpg isn't seen from login and error pages. From chat page it is seen.
[image: WebContent]

Comment: i which file did you write this code   background-image: url(img/background.jpg);    is it in a jsp or a css which is included in jsp?

Comment: when you dont get an image on screen you probably get a blank space or a X there...right click on it and copy the full image URL...open it in a new tab and see if the URl is correct as per your folder structure.

Comment: It's in jsp in <style></style>.

Comment: then check the URL as i said earlier. IF the JSP file is directly in WebContent then ./img/abc.jsp should give you the path to the image file. But if JSP file is again structured in folders within WebContent then relative paths need to be done. Can you add the folder structures in WebContent in your question.

Comment: I can't check as you advise. There is no X or blank space for the image.

Comment: @Nazgul, you suggest me an idea! I tried to access the file directly from browser. I was redirected to login page. The reason is the filter which has to redirect all requests from not loginned users. After adding
'String currPage = req.getRequestURI();
  if (!currPage.endsWith("jpg") && !currPage.endsWith("css")) {doFilter()}'

it works!
Thank you very much!

Comment: perhaps you can upvote my comment if it helped :)

Comment: @Nazgul, unfortunately i can't upvote comments. (Or I don't know how to do that.)

Comment: Its ok anyway. Do come back to SO if and when you get stuck again. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you have Eclipse you have to put the image here:

> workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/ProjectName

and then write

```
background-image: url(<%request.getContextPath()%>/background.jpg);
```

It seems CSS, but i don't know CSS so i'm not sure that the code above is correct. For example in HTML the correct syntax is:

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>\Background.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

So. The reason is the filter which has to redirect all requests from not loginned users. After adding

```
String currPage = req.getRequestURI();
if (!currPage.endsWith("jpg") && !currPage.endsWith("css")) {doFilter()}
```

it works!